# Force Chrome/Chromium to use Adwaita Dark theme

Tags: 14.04, gnome, google-chrome

Is there a way to force Chrome/Chromium to use Adwaita Dark theme? Using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

I've managed to force Qt and every other apps to use Dark theme (by changing gtk-css), but I can't figure out how to force Chrome to use Dark theme for at least title bar.

Comment: Have you selected "Use GTK+ Theme" in Settings?

Comment: Yes, but Chrome is still using default Adwaita Light.